# ReactJS difference between setting state directly and through method argument

Tags: reactjs

I have started learning ReactJS and realize that there are two way I can change the state. Both works fine without any error or warning.

> What is the main difference? is there a reason or need I should use second version?

**consider I want to modify following state on each click**

```
this.state = { count: 0 }
```

**First Version**

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count+1})
}
```

**Second Version**

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prvState => {
        return {
            count: prvState+1
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Because of the reason that setState method is asynchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you are setting the next state value based on the previous state
>   value then passing in a `function` (second version) as the first
>   parameter of `this.setState` instead of an `object` is the **recommended**
>   solution.

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prvState => {
        return {
            count: prvState+1
        }
    })
}
```

The reason is that `this.state` may be updated asynchronously and that's why you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

In the first version, there's a high possibility that the value of `count` is incorrect especially once your application gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on the previous state (like in your case you need the previous counter value), the second approach is preferred. It guarantees that `prvState` holds the current state. This is important if you have two `setState` modifying the state in the same render loop (remember that React may batch multiple `setState` calls together), e.g.

```
this.setState({count: this.state.count+1})
this.setState({count: this.state.count+1})
```

has the problem that the `count` gets only incremented once. While

```
this.setState((prevState) => {count: prevState.count+1})
this.setState((prevState) => {count: prevState.count+1})
```

guarantees that it gets incremented twice as intended (independent of the order the `setState` are handled by React)